# Google-style cards (issue)

Tags: java, android

I'm just a novice who's JUST started learning to make android apps using tutorials etc... 
I just found some code to make Google-style cards, and I wrote the code but for some reason it seems  to have errors.

In my static, it can't "convert from object to Typeface", it's calling it a mismatch.
Also, it cannot resolve "commandText" (`myListItem.descText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commandText);`)

Any help possible?

Thanks much, here is the code:

```
ArrayListAdapter.java-

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import java.util.List;

 

import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Typeface;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;

 

public class NowArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

 private Context context;

 private ArrayList<String> values;

 private Typeface typeface;

 private static Hashtable fontCache = new Hashtable();

 private LayoutInflater inflater;

 

 public class CustomListItem {

  TextView descText;

  

 }

 

 public NowArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> commandsList) {

  //TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

  super(context, R.layout.list_item, commandsList);

  this.context = context;

  values = new ArrayList<String>();

  values.addAll(commandsList);

  typeface = getTypeface(this.context, "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");

  inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

 }

 

 static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, String font) {

  Typeface typeface = fontCache.get(font);

  if (typeface == null) {

   typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font);

   fontCache.put(font, typeface);

  }

  return typeface;

  

 }

 

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  CustomListItem myListItem;

  String myText = getItem(position);

  

  if(convertView == null) {

   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

   myListItem = new CustomListItem();

   

   myListItem.descText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commandText);

   myListItem.descText.setTypeface(typeface);

   

   convertView.setTag(myListItem);

  } else { 

   myListItem = (CustomListItem) convertView.getTag();

  }

  

  myListItem.descText.setText(myText);

  //myListItem.descText.setTextSize(14)

  

  return convertView;

 }

 

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and format your code to be readable. Also, what are the errors?

Comment: 'It seems to have errors' is not a good description of your problem. What are you expecting and what's actually happening?

Comment: @Edward how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you need to specify your types when you define the fontCache Hashtable. Since you're looking up a Typeface via a String, use these types in your definition:

```
private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();
```

Secondly, if `R.id.commandText` cannot be resolved then it is not present in your R.java resources file. Make sure you have created a view in R.layout.list_item with the `android:id` attribute set to `"@+id/commandText"`. If you've already done this, perhaps you need to clean & rebuild your project to force R.java to be recreated.

Comment: Thanks much, the commandText issue was resolved. However, where am I supposed to add the " private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();"  code?

Comment: I'm not going to tell you. ;) Look for where you are currently defining `fontCache = new Hashtable()` and make my suggested changes.

Comment: Ah finally got it (you can see how bad i am at the lol). Thanks much for the help man! :)

Comment: Excellent, nice work. Remember to accept & upvote helpful answers. :)

Comment: No worries, if you get it later on feel free to come back and vote.